# split IO and computation

Tags: haskell

I want to receive a string, convert it to a list and write every element of the list into a TChan. For every string received I want to fork a new process.

My problem is that I get errors related to IO when I try to compile this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[()]'
```

or

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[IO ()]'
```

Whilst I completely understand the error and know where it originates from ( - at least the first error - ) I am now out of ideas how I could split IO an computation in my example and still achieve what I try to do.

```
write2TChan msg mtch = do
        let mymessages = words msg
        map (\x -> atomically $ writeTChan mtch x) mymessages
        return ()

main = withSocketsDo $ do
        s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
        bindAddr <- inet_addr host
        bindSocket s (SockAddrInet port bindAddr)
        mtch <- newTChanIO
        let forever socket hosts = do
                (msg, host) <- receiveMessage socket
                return ()
                return (forkIO $ write2TChan msg mtch)
                --forkIO $ write2TChan msg mtch
                --tried w return () and above, same problem
                forever socket hosts
        forever s []
        sClose s
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` has the type `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, so it always returns a *list*. However, every statement in a `do` block in the `IO` monad must have type `IO a` for some `a`.

You want the related function `mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]` which does the same thing in a monad. Since you want to ignore the result, we can use the variant `mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()`.

```
write2TChan msg mtch = do
    let mymessages = words msg
    mapM_ (\x -> atomically $ writeTChan mtch x) mymessages
```

For your other function you should be able to use `forkIO` directly. Wrapping it in `return` makes no sense at all, as that would make the type `IO (IO a)`, i.e. an action returning an action. Also, `return ()` is a no-op when it's not the last statement in a `do` block, so you don't need that.

This should work

```
let forever socket hosts = do
         (msg, host) <- receiveMessage socket
         forkIO $ write2TChan msg mtch
         forever socket hosts
```

though, the `hosts` argument is currently always `[]`, so unless you plan to do something about that, you can get rid of that, too. Also, I would avoid the name `forever` since there is already a commonly used function in `Control.Monad` with that name.

Comment: Slightly off topic: would it make a big difference to use the par combinator instead of forkIO? I am concerned that in my example the number of threads is not limited of course.

Comment: @JFritsch: `par` is for parallelism in pure code. Here, you're doing concurrency with lots of side effects, not parallelism, so `par` isn't even an option to begin with. Also, remember that `forkIO` spawns lightweight Haskell threads, so unless you're spawning thousands of them, I wouldn't be too concerned about it.